# Cue ball foul in 8 ball

Tags: rules, pool

We had a game the other night where the cue ball jumped off the table rolling on the wood surface and then hitting the metal silver lining around the pocket and returned to the bed of table, and I called foul. I was over ruled saying it didn't hit the floor and returned to the bed of table. Please, what is the correct call there?

Answer (score 3):

From [the rule book](http://www.wpa-pool.com/web/index.asp?id=123&pagetype=rules#8.5):

> Driven off the Table
>
> A ball is considered driven off the table if it comes to rest other
>   than on the playing surface but is not pocketed. A ball is also
>   considered driven off the table if it would have been driven off the
>   table except for striking an object such as a light fixture, piece of
>   chalk or a player which causes it to return to the table.
>
> A ball that contacts the top of the rail is not considered to have
>   been driven off the table if it returns to the playing surface or
>   enters a pocket.

Not so clear cut, given your description, but I'd argue for foul if the ball would've fallen off the table had it not hit the part of the pocket.

Answer (score 1):

The ball struck the metal lining around the pocket, which is part of the table.
So this was not a foul, according to the rule given by @jacob-g.